# lucene index with relative (and changed) document path

Tags: path, lucene, document, relative-path

Is there a way to do the following:

- create a lucene index on machine "a" with documents at location "a1",
- move documents to location "a2",
- modify index to reflect the modified path?

Goal is to move index together with documents on to a CD or USB stick with relative path to documents ...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have file in `/somepath/file` and you want to magically reappear it under `/otherpath/file`. Unfortunately, any modification to the index contents will require reindexing :-(

If it is enough for you to query on static part ("file"), I would recommend you indexing the static part only.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the full context of the problem.
However, this is definitely possible after opening a new IndexWriter on the new Directory (this is not OS file system dir, but Lucene Directory which is an abstraction over OS file system directory).

If you have copied all the index files in the new location, and in your application using Lucene, change the location of the index (assuming that this location is read somehow by Lucene's IndexWriter), you should be all set, provided: all the index segments use the codec supported by the Lucene version you are using. For eg: Lucene 3 will not read index files created by Lucene 4 index.

For eg, you can easily do this in Solr. In case you are using Solr Cores, then all you have to do is make a new core, copy all index files inside the new core's data/index directory - reload the core, and you should be all set.

Comment: I´m rather new to lucene and therefore sure not to catch the concept clearly ...
Of course I can use solr within tomcat move the whole server, and all will be fine...

Comment: Sorry, again: I´m rather new ... Of course I can use solr within tomcat move the whole server, and all will be ok. But is there a way to generate a lucene  file system index at location "a" for data files at "a1", move index files and data files to a movable location like CD or USB stick, adapt index files to reflect the new conditions, and then read the index with carrot2 workbench (to my knowledge the only carrot2 implementation with Aduna clustering capabilities). So please if your explanation above is a solution for what I want to do, whar should I read to catch the details? Thanks in adv.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this comment while I was googling for something else :)

Comment: Lucene index files carry no file system information within them. Lucene abstracts filesystem details under the class called "FSDirectory". Directory is used while indexing and searching both. So for eg, if you use MMapDirectory and the file system does not support that, then you need to change the Directory object used for indexing and searching. You do not have to do anything to index files, they can be just copied around as long as lucene version is same on different servers.